# C#: keeping variables in Visual Studio's memory between program compiles

Tags: c#, matlab, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have a computationally intense program that starts by filling a very large array using data from a binary file.  The program then goes on to manipulate this data, etc.  Loading my variable from the bin file is the most time consuming step.

Is there a way to keep the variable in Visual Studio's memory so I can just edit/recompile the meat of the program, without repeating this loading process each time?

I'm coming from Matlab, where I could load a variable into the workspace and then use it as much as I wanted from any script until I closed the Matlab environment.

Comment: No, variables can't be stored in Visual Studio like in Matlab. VS is an IDE for writing programs, and Matlab is a computational package.

Comment: You may check out articles on adding C# scripting to game editors. Usually they support hot script reload for exactly this reason.

Comment: The question needs more detail for a useful answer. Depending on what you want to do, there can be different solutions to your problem, like serving the data from a service through REST or a named pipe, memory mapped files or dynamically loading and unloading an app domain with the calculation portion of the code. I can’t see a way though to do this within VS, even with an extension. How would you pass the data on from VS to your application?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. You will have to load it to memory everytime you compile. Matlab is very different from C#. As you said it runs scripts under a closed environment.
C# compiles a standalone program that communicates with Visual Studio (debug version), but doesn't belong to VS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with Visual Studio, but you might consider using an in memory cache like [redis](https://redis.io/) to store your data. It's a bit of a pain to set up on Windows, so I recommend getting it via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis-64).  Once it's running [StackExchange.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/) is the go to provider.

Answer (score -1):

loading huge data into memory is not time consuming, processing it is time consuming.

loading huge files mostly depends on read speed of disk drive. if you have SSD that should not take more than few seconds.

anyway, you can always store your data in form of json or somewhat contrived way, store binary form of your data (deserialized) into disk.

you will load your baked data from disk, rather than getting raw data and processing it again.